# Using a CASE statement in a WHERE clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I am trying to create query form on a website.  First object is a dropdown list with operators. Default first value in the dropdown list is NULL(1), second value is LIKE(2), etc...  Second object is a textbox where the user can enter a string like "A".

Therefore, I am trying to build the below SQL query to simulate the variables coming from the website.  It runs and returns all values when the `@op = 1`.  But I keep getting the following error when I change `@op = 2`:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Tom LIKE A%' to data type int."

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2(7) = '2017-11-08 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME2(7) = '2017-11-08 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00'
DECLARE @Op INT = 2
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(25) = 'A'
SELECT
    name, 
    dttm
FROM 
    tableName 
WHERE 
    dttm BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND CASE @Op
        WHEN 1 THEN 1
        WHEN 2 THEN name + ' LIKE ' + @name +'%'
        END <> 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `case`.  Just use regular boolean logic:

```
WHERE dttm BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND
      ( (@op = 1) OR
        (@op = 2 AND name LIKE @name + '%')
      )
```

Your specific issue involves constructing a `LIKE` comparison in a string.  However, the above appears to be what you want to do.